# check if an element is present geckofx c#

Tags: c#, gecko, geckofx

The title is self-explanatory. I want to check if an element is present in the geckofx browser.

```
if(geckoWebBrowser1.Document.getElementByClassName("classname")[0] != null)
{ do something; }
```

This code is not working and throws specified index was out of range of valid values error.

Comment: What happens if you remove the indexer? `[0]`

Answer (score 0):

I usually check same way as you do, but without indexer [0]